# Large current flow through SMD shunt resistor

Tags: pcb-design, current-measurement

What is the best way to large current flow through SMD resistor?

As you know, latest FPGA like ULTRA series or Versal series need large Core current almost over the hundred ampere.

It is not problem, if i not use shunt resistor or use expensive DC/DC regulator that has power management function(can get measuring output voltage or current), because they connected through just copper plane from voltage source to FPGA.

If i use shunt resistor and that has not enough big smd pads, i think it will be make problem.

Because i can make big enough copper island but current must flow through shunt resistor smaller and narrower than island.

is there any good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put multiple shunt resistors in parallel or you can use a copper trace as a shunt resistor.

Comment: yes.. as you mentioned, That's the best and simple way 'use more shunt resistor parallel'